# Print statements in SQL merge

Tags: sql-server

I've been asked to include some debugging PRINT statement in a SQL merge, which I'm new to. I've been told that OUTPUT isn't satisfactory.

```
MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target
    USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
    ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Name = source.Name
        PRINT "Updated"
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
        VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)
        PRINT "Inserted"
```

This isn't working, as it appears each conditional block should contain a single SQL command.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Production.UnitMeasure  WHERE UnitMeasureCode = @UnitMeasureCode)
  BEGIN
     UPDATE Production.UnitMeasure
        SET Name = @Name
     WHERE  UnitMeasureCode = @UnitMeasureCode
     PRINT 'Updated'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
     INSERT Production.UnitMeasure (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
     VALUES (@UnitMeasureCode, @Name)
     PRINT 'Inserted'
  END
```

Or another approach could be

```
     UPDATE Production.UnitMeasure
        SET Name = @Name
     WHERE  UnitMeasureCode = @UnitMeasureCode

 IF (@@ROWCOUNT <> 0)
  BEGIN
     PRINT 'Updated'
  END
ELSE  
  BEGIN
     INSERT Production.UnitMeasure (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
     VALUES (@UnitMeasureCode, @Name)
     PRINT 'Inserted'
  END
```

Comment: We've begun standardizing with MERGE for a couple reasons. Is my take away here that PRINT statements within MERGE conditionals are not allowed?

Comment: I dont use merge statements for a number of reasons Have a look here [`Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). Hence I do not have much experience of working with Merge statements also I have never seen more than One statement being executed in Merge clauses (Matched/not matched) except output clause.

Comment: As you can see in the link Merge Statement has almost 13 active bugs, I would suggest my team to stay away from it and stick to old ways of 'IF EXISTS` and wait till all of these bugs are fixed :)

Comment: Thanks for the input @M.Ali! For anyone else who stumbles on this question, I was only able to resolve my issue by OUTPUTing to a temp table, and PRINTing off that.